# What is Best Practice for mapping a comment table to multiple tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, comments

I am looking to find the best practice in mapping one base table to multiple tables.  For example if I had any one of the following base tables (comments,tags,favorites,ratings), it could map to one or more tables such as (blog post, picture, video).  The example below can provide a better explanation.

*More info:*
I am looking to use these tables to create a Yii application which uses Active Record.

*My proposed solution (Mysql):*
My Base Table

```
create table comment (
 id int(4) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
 attach_id int(4) unsigned not null,           #used to attach to a specific post/photo/video
 attach_type_id tinyint(1) unsigned not null,  #foreign key to attach_type(id)
 comment text not null,
 user_id int(4) unsigned null,
 datetime_added datetime not null,
 foreign key (attach_type_id) references attach_type(id)
);
```

My "Global Mapping" Table:

```
create table attach_type (
 id tinyint(1) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
 table_name varchar(20) not null  #used for reference purposes only
);
```

Primitive Example of two of the "Multiple" Tables:

```
create table blog_post (
 id int(4) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
 title varchar(100) not null,
 post text not null,
 user_id int(4) unsigned null,
 datetime_added datetime not null
);

create table photo (
 id int(4) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
 title varchar(100) not null,
 description varchar(255) null,
 file_name varchar(100) not null,
 user_id int(4) unsigned null,
 datetime_added datetime not null
);
```

*To retrieve all comments for blog post id=54*
blog_post table's id for its row in the attach_type table = 1
The post's row id for its row in the blog_post table = 54

```
select * from comments where attach_type_id=1 and attach_id=54;
```

So a (comment,tag,favorite,rating), comment seen above, can be attached to both a blog_post and/or a photo.  Likewise multiple comments can be attached to a single blog_post / photo (allows for multiple users to comment).  My question is what is the best way to go about this in mysql.  Does the above look like a proper setup or would you suggest a better way and why.  And also if using the above solution, does anyone forsee any glaring cons?  Thank you for your response in advance, I'm simply trying to figure out the best way to go about doing this.

I believe this topic is related to what I am asking, but did not really answer my question:
[Database tables, one table referencing multiple unrelated tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999268/database-tables-one-table-referencing-multiple-unrelated-tables)

Answer (score 0):

[Tom H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16036/tom-h) supplied an answer to another question which I believe answered my question.  I do not know how to give him the proper credit but the link to his solution is here:
[Database tables, one table referencing multiple unrelated tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999268/database-tables-one-table-referencing-multiple-unrelated-tables)

Thank you for your assistance Tom.

I'm still open to suggestions but taking into account the information posted in the link above I think I'm going to go the route of making multiple map tables.